# NSRangeException index beyond bounds error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using a face multiplier app, and trying to determine why it is crashing with the error;

```
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
```

The method swapTapped I believe is causing the issue somewhere along the line...

```
//Create collection
    faceViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int faceIndex;

- (IBAction)swapTapped:(id)sender {
    //Play sound
    [[AVAudio sharedAudio] playSound: @"explosion"];

    //Show flash
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.flashView];
    self.flashView.alpha = 1.0;
    self.flashView.hidden = FALSE;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.flashView.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.flashView.hidden = TRUE;
    }];

    //Make all faces the same
    faceIndex++;

    if (faceIndex >= self.faceViews.count)
    {
        return;
    }

        FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex]; //  I believe it crashes here

    UIImage *baseImage = faceViewIndex.baseImage;
    for (FaceView *fv in self.faceViews)
        [fv setFaceImage: baseImage];
}
```

Here is another method;

```
-(void) swapFaces {
    //Deselect all faces
    [self deselectFaces];

    //Reset tag flag to zero
    for (FaceView *crtFaceView in self.faceViews)
        crtFaceView.tag = 0;

    //Swap each photo
    for (int i=0; i<[self.faceViews count];i++) {
        //Get current and next
        FaceView *crtFaceView = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: i];
        FaceView *nxtFaceView = crtFaceView == [self.faceViews lastObject] ? [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: 0] : [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: i+1];

        //Only not swaped yet
        if (crtFaceView.tag == 0 && nxtFaceView.tag == 0) {
            //Change flag
            crtFaceView.tag = 1;
            nxtFaceView.tag = 1;

            //Calculate scale
            float ratioX = nxtFaceView.bounds.size.width / crtFaceView.bounds.size.width;
            float ratioY = nxtFaceView.bounds.size.height / crtFaceView.bounds.size.height;

            //Auto saturation matching
            crtFaceView.saturation = nxtFaceView.meanSaturation / crtFaceView.meanSaturation;
            crtFaceView.brightness = nxtFaceView.meanBrightness / crtFaceView.meanBrightness;

            //Auto flip
            if (crtFaceView.faceType != nxtFaceView.faceType && crtFaceView.faceType != 0 && nxtFaceView.faceType != 0) {
                crtFaceView.flipped = TRUE;
                nxtFaceView.flipped = TRUE;
            } else {
                crtFaceView.flipped = FALSE;
                nxtFaceView.flipped = FALSE;
            }

            //Animate to position
            [UIView beginAnimations: @"" context: nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

            //Save original frame and transform
            CGPoint tempCenter = crtFaceView.originalCenter;
            CGAffineTransform tempTransform = crtFaceView.originalTransform;

            //Swap object one
            crtFaceView.center = nxtFaceView.originalCenter;
            crtFaceView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(nxtFaceView.originalTransform, ratioX, ratioY);

            //Swap object two
            nxtFaceView.center = tempCenter;
            nxtFaceView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(tempTransform, 1/ratioX, 1/ratioY);

            //Commit animation
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
}
```

A guaranteed way to get the app to crash is to press the swapTapped button 3 times, its like it cycles through, but crashes out when it thinks the index is beyond bounds...?

Edit- It crashes on this line;

```
FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex];
```

Comment: That did not stop the error unfortunately

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: I have added another method 'swapFaces' I think the Faceview array is causing the issue

Comment: You think? Why don't you know for sure? Use the debugger and you will know exactly where the error is happening. Please edit your question to clearly indicate the exact line causing the error.

Comment: Hi rmaddy, sorry I had just updated it you were too fast for me :)

Comment: For the 3rd time, please edit your question and point out the exact line of code causing the error.

Comment: The final section I posted

Answer (score 0):

In case, you wish to overcome this crash, add

```
 if(faceIndex < [self.faceViews count] && [self.faceViews count] > 0)  {
     FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex]; 
    }
```

Comment: So the new method should look like this? `// New method
    faceIndex++;
    
    if(faceIndex < [self.faceViews count]) {
        FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex];
    }
    
    FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex];
    
    UIImage *baseImage = faceViewIndex.baseImage;
    for (FaceView *fv in self.faceViews)
        [fv setFaceImage: baseImage];
    
}
// End new method`

Comment: yes @Hypergater!  ask/reply me if needed any other help?

Comment: ok add if(faceIndex < [self.faceViews count] &&  [self.faceViews count] > 0)

Comment: what you actually want to do?? @Hypergater

Comment: The app cycles through the faces in a photograph, so if you have 5 people, it will clone the face of one, and place on others, when you press the button underneath, it cycles through the faces that it has captured.

Rajesh's answer below, fixes it, but stops the cycle, so only one face is ever cloned, whereas your fix, unfortunately still crashes the app when trying to cycle through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137695/discussion-between-hypergater-and-nikdange-me).

Comment: What is issue sean @Hypergater?

Answer (score -1):

// I don't know where you increment exactly

```
faceIndex++; 

    if (faceIndex < self.faceViews.count)
     {
     FaceView *faceViewIndex = [self.faceViews objectAtIndex: faceIndex]; 

        UIImage *baseImage = faceViewIndex.baseImage;
        for (FaceView *fv in self.faceViews)
            [fv setFaceImage: baseImage];

    }
```

Comment: This stops the crash on the 3rd tap my example photo has 4 people, and with this method I am able to cycle the faces of each BUT once I click past that, If I try to proceed, the app crashes, so I need to find out how to restrict it to only be able to click the amount of times of people on screen.